# How to define a (n, 0) sparse matrix in scipy or how to assemble a sparse matrix column wise?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a loop that in each iteration gives me a column `c` of a sparse matrix `N`.

To assemble/grow/accumulate `N` column by column I thought of using

```
N = scipy.sparse.hstack([N, c])
```

To do this it would be nice to initialize the matrix with  with rows of length 0. However,

```
N = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((4,0))
```

raises a `ValueError: invalid shape`.

Any suggestions, how to do this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Sparse matrices are restricted compared to NumPy arrays and in particular don't allow `0` for any axis. All sparse matrix constructors check for this, so if and when you do manage to build such a matrix, you're exploiting a SciPy bug and your script is likely to break when you upgrade SciPy.

<del>That being said, I don't see why you'd need an *n* × 0 sparse matrix since an *n* × 0 NumPy array is allowed and takes practically no storage space.</del>

Turns out `sparse.hstack` cannot handle a NumPy array with a zero axis, so disregard my previous comment. However, what I think you should do is collect all the columns in a list, then `hstack` them in one call. That's better than your loop since `append`'ing to a list takes amortized constant time, while `hstack` takes linear time. So your proposed algorithm takes quadratic time while it could be linear.

Comment: Thank you, that all makes perfect sense. I will use the lists!

Answer (score 1):

You must use at least `1` in your shape.

```
N = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((4,1))
```

Which you can stack:

```
print scipy.sparse.hstack( (N,N) )
#<4x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
#    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I am looking for a (4,0) matrix.